# how to store data of text file into a string

Tags: string-comparison, file-handling

My text file name *pass* has text *1234* but when I pick this text from file and compare with string  *epass* which is also *1234* using the code below it cannot match it. Why are there two strings not equal?

```
try {
    InputStream fr = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pass);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
    String s=br.readLine().toString().trim();
    if(epass.equals(s))
    {
        t.setText("");

        Intent main= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(main);
        this.finish();
    }
    else
    {
        show.setText("Wrong Passcode");
        show.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        t.setText("");
        epass="";
    }
    epass="";
}
catch(IOException ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you insert the follwing code after `String s=br.readLine().toString().trim();`, what is the output?

```
    System.out.println("'" + s + "'");
    System.out.println("'" + epass + "'");
```

maybe there is problem with an end-of-line character or something similar

Comment: 12-24 18:38:04.474 14976-14976/com.example.adnaninayat.myapplication I/System.out: '1234'
12-24 18:38:04.474 14976-14976/com.example.adnaninayat.myapplication I/System.out: '1234'

Comment: very strange.. what happens if you compare like this: `Integer.valueOf(s) == Integer.valueOf(epass)` ?

Comment: lot of errors when i write Integer.valueOf(s) == Integer.valueOf(epass)